# How to check the values are increasing or decreasing between different columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, file-filter

In the table below each row has a different behavior. Note that, In the first row, the columns "pool1" the values are decreasing. Also decreasing for columns "pool2" and "pool3".

In the second row the values first increase and then decrease (5.15761 < 27.6797 > 12.3756). The same for all the other pools.

Some are increasing, some are decreasing, some increase and then decrease, some decrease and then increase. Is there a function for identifying this behavior?

Also, I'd like to automatically assign the designated behavior (increasing/decreasing/other) a distinct color.

[image]

```
tracking_id FPKM_ANTpool1   FPKM_AT1NTpool1 FPKM_CANTpool1  FPKM_ANTpool2   FPKM_AT1NTpool2 FPKM_CANTpool2  FPKM_ANTpool3   FPKM_AT1NTpool3 FPKM_CANTpool3
NM_000024   30.4457 14.1371 4.0972  27.9215 13.6887 3.08018 22.3328 12.0171 3.20291
NM_000110   5.15761 27.6797 12.3756 4.09535 29.2773 11.0238 5.64573 25.0115 11.9133
NM_000112   45.3095 20.7874 9.75086 31.428  18.5596 9.13031 54.2335 18.7279 10.8629
NM_000138   1.50201 0.374563    0.104122    0.925782    0.523696    0.0846463   1.28962 0.419237    0.0855848
NM_000199   1.7078  0.0900816   0.911752    1.80376 0.00895961  1.03933 1.48653 0.0345055   0.96731
```

Comment: How many different colors are you planning to use, including no color as 1 choice?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But I tried myself and it worked. I used "IF" statement.

Comment: What do you mean in your comment, **" I tried myself and it worked"**? Can you please include details by [edit]ing your question to include what you did that worked. What version of Excel are you using?